Showing interior product of differential form is zero
I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $M$ be a smooth orientable $n$-manifold, with a smooth differential $(n-1)$-form $\omega$. Show there exists a vector field $X$, with $X(p)\neq0$ whenever $\omega(p)\neq0$, such that $i_X\omega\equiv0$.

Here $i_X\omega$ is the interior product. Working locally, I have been able to solve this I believe, using the interior product formula here:
\begin{align*}
\omega &= \sum_{j=1}^n f_jdx^1\wedge \cdots \hat{dx^j}\cdots\wedge dx^n\\\\
X &= \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1}f_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\\\\
i_X\omega &= \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k\neq j}(-1)^{j<k}f_jf_kdx^1\wedge\cdots\hat{dx^j}\cdots\hat{dx^k}\cdots\wedge dx^n
\end{align*}
The coefficient in the above sum of $dx^1\wedge\cdots\hat{dx^j}\cdots\hat{dx^k}\cdots\wedge dx^n$ for $j<k$ is $f_kf_j-f_jf_k=0$. So $i_X\omega\equiv 0$. But that leaves me with a couple of questions:

Can this local argument be used to construct the global vector field?
Is there a more conceptual reason $X$ exists, that doesn't require so much local work & computation?


enough to construct it locally. Use a bump function so that the vector field is zero elsewhere.

@CraniumClamp: thank you for the comment. This idea (using partitions of unity) did occur to me, but isnt there danger of introducing new zeroes in the final (global) vector field?

I’m sorry, I misread the question. I thought it was a single point p whereas the question asks for every point p with the condition

The local approach should work, but I think that giving an answer to the second question will be more satisfactory. Let's use the hypothesis of the manifold being orientable, so that there is a nowhere-vanishing volume form $\Omega$. I claim that for any $(n-1)$-form $\omega$, we can find a vector field $X$ such that $$\omega=\iota_X\Omega.$$ In particular, we will also get $\iota_X\omega=\iota_X\iota_X\Omega=0$. We can express $X$, $\omega$, and $\Omega$ in a local system of coordinates $\mathbf{x}=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ for the manifold as
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
X=\sum_iX^i\partial_{x^i}\\
\omega=\sum_j\omega_j dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{d x^j}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n\\
\Omega=f\,dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
and the equation $\omega=\iota_X\Omega$ becomes
\begin{equation}\label{eq:vectorfield_solution}
\tag{$\star$}
X^j=(-1)^{j+1}\frac{\omega_j}{f},
\end{equation}
using the same type of computations that you performed. In particular you see that if $\omega$ does not vanish, $X$ does not vanish either.
So, we have locally determined a vector field with the desired property. We should also check that these local expressions patch together to globally define a vector field!
For each local coordinate set of our manifold $\mathbf{x}\colon U_{\mathbf{x}}\to\mathbb{R}$ we have defined a vector field on $U_{\mathbf{x}}$, let's call it $X_{\mathbf{x}}=\sum_i X^i(\mathbf{x})\partial_{x^i}$, where each of the $X^i$ is a real function. We want to make sure that there is a global vector field $X$ such that over each coordinate set $U_{\mathbf{x}}$ we have $X_{\restriction U_{\mathbf{x}}}=X_{\mathbf{x}}$. The condition for this to be true, i.e. for the locally defined vector fields to "patch together" to a global one, is that whenever we have two overlapping coordinate sets $\mathbf{x}\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{y}\colon V\to\mathbb{R}$, it must be $X_{\mathbf{x}}{}_{\restriction U\cap V}=X_{\mathbf{y}}{}_{\restriction U\cap V}$. Another way of saying this is that the functions $X^i(\mathbf{x})$ should satisfy the transformation rule (or change of coordinates formula)
\begin{equation}\label{eq:vf_coordchange}
\tag{$\textbf{c.c.}$}
X^i(\mathbf{x})=\sum_jX^j(\mathbf{y})\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}.\end{equation}
So, how do we verify that the local functions defined by \eqref{eq:vectorfield_solution} satisfy \eqref{eq:vf_coordchange}? One quick (and correct) way is to appeal to the equation our local vector fields satisfy, namely $\omega=\iota_{X_{\mathbf{x}}}\Omega$. As both $\omega$ and $\Omega$ are global objects and the local vector field $X_{\mathbf{x}}$ is uniquely determined by $\omega$ and $\Omega$, it must also satisfy the change of coordinates formula.
We can also check directly that \eqref{eq:vectorfield_solution} implies \eqref{eq:vf_coordchange} by using the change of coordinate formulas for $\omega$ and $\Omega$, but as you can see it is not completely straightforward! Let's first obtain the change of coordinates formula for $\Omega$: we need to use the fact that for any two overlapping coordinate charts $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ one has $dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge dy^n=\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\right)dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n$ up to a sign (which sign is not important for us now). Then, for the volume form:
$$\Omega=f(\mathbf{x})dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n=f(\mathbf{y})dy^1\wedge\dots\wedge dy^n$$
and using the previous relation for the wedge power of the differentials we find $$f(\mathbf{x})dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n=f(\mathbf{y})\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial{\mathbf{x}}}\right)dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n.$$ So we can conclude that $f(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{y})\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial{\mathbf{x}}}\right)$, which is the coordinate change formula for $\Omega$. Obtaining the change of coordinates formula for $\omega$ is a little more tricky. First, observe that for every $i$, $$dx^i\wedge\omega=(-1)^{i-1}\omega_i(\mathbf{x}) dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n.$$ On the other hand, $$dx^i\wedge\omega=\sum_j\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}dy^j\wedge\omega,$$ from which we get $$(-1)^{i-1}\omega_i(\mathbf{x}) dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n=\sum_j\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}(-1)^{j-1}\omega_j(\mathbf{y}) dy^1\wedge\dots dy^n=\sum_j\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}(-1)^{j-1}\omega_j(\mathbf{y})\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\right) dx^1\wedge\dots dx^n.$$
Comparing the two expression we finally arrive at the change of coordinates formula: $$\omega_i(\mathbf{x})=\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\right)\sum_j(-1)^{i+j}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}\omega_j(\mathbf{y}).$$
Now, from \eqref{eq:vectorfield_solution} we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
X^i(\mathbf{x})=(-1)^{i+1}\frac{\omega_i(\mathbf{x})}{f(\mathbf{x})}\\
X^j(\mathbf{y})=(-1)^{j+1}\frac{\omega_j(\mathbf{y})}{f(\mathbf{y})}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
and the change of coordinate formulas for $\Omega$ and $\omega$ give us
\begin{equation}
X^i(\mathbf{x})=(-1)^{i+1}\frac{\omega_i(\mathbf{x})}{f(\mathbf{x})}=(-1)^{i+1}\frac{\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\right)\sum_j(-1)^{i+j}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}\omega_j(\mathbf{y})}{f(\mathbf{y})\det\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{y}}{\partial{\mathbf{x}}}\right)}=
\sum_j\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}(-1)^{j+1}\frac{\omega_j(\mathbf{y})}{f(\mathbf{y})}=\sum_j\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}X^j(\mathbf{y})
\end{equation}
which is exactly \eqref{eq:vf_coordchange}, so our local vector fields do in fact define a global one!

Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate being able to see the underlying reason why this should always work. For patching the local solutions together, do I need a partition of unity type argument? My gut is that we don't, because the local expression for $X$ makes use of $\omega$ and $\Omega$, which have global definitions. But I can't figure out how to formalize that reasoning.

@Hempelicious From this point of view we do not need to use a partition of unity. To be more precise: for each coordinate set $U$, the above reasoning defines a vector field $X_U$. We should now check that all of these $X_U$ are in fact the local expressions of a global vector field $X$ on the manifold. To do that, it is enough to check that for two non-disjoint coordinate sets $U$ and $V$, $X_U$ restricted to $U\cap V$ coincides with the restriction of $X_V$. In this case the computation is not completely straightforward, I'd be happy to edit the answer with more details if you'd like.

Yes, seeing how this is done would help solidify this type of argument for me (which I'll admit I can't produce myself). Thank you again!

No problem! I'll update my answer with the details as soon as I have time - probably at some point tomorrow

@Hempelicious I updated the answer with the computation, hope this helps.

Thank you this makes it super clear!
